# when saving form I need it to save and continue on the same page

Tags: python, django

I need to save the form, it stays on the same page with the updated form that was saved that does not go to core_list_movrotative but stays in 'core / update_movrotativos.html'

```
@login_required    
    def movrotativos_update(request, id):
        data = {}
        mov_rotativo = MovRotativo.objects.get(id=id)
        form = MovRotativoForm(request.POST or None, instance=mov_rotativo)
        data['mov_rotativo'] = mov_rotativo
        data['form'] = form

         if request.method == 'POST':
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return redirect('core_lista_movrotativos')
        else:
            return render(request, 'core/update_movrotativos.html', data)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in here:

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('core_lista_movrotativos')
```

On the last line there, you redirect to `core_lista_movrotativos`

You should, just like when it's not a POST method, redirect to the current page:
`render(request, 'core/update_movrotativos.html', data)`.

Comment: it worked fine, but now when it saves and stays on the same page the checkout = models.DateTimeField (null = True, blank = True) does not update with the data, only if I exit and enter the page